# Video.js and RTMP stream fails on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, video, rtmp, video.js

I'm having a problem with Video.js , RTMP stream and Firefox .

I've created a test page with only a video.js player who display a RTMP flux .

It works great on Chrome/IE 11 but when I try this on Firefox i get this error message in developper console :

> "Specified "type" attribute of "rtmp/mp4" is not supported. Load of media >resource rtmp://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx failed ."

Is there a way to make this runnable on Firefox or I have to find an other solution ?

Thank You .

Comment: Do you have Flash installed and enabled?

Comment: Oh god , thanks x) I thought Flash was installed ... It works great now , thank you : )

Comment: Why it is not played without flash player? I want to use html5 video for this, is it possible?